# Looking for references regarding the history of metaphysics, and specially of ontology

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, history-of-philosophy, ontology

Although many histories of ethics, of esthetics or of logic are available, it seems more difficult to find histories regarding other domains of philosophy. This is the case for epistemology and for metaphysics/ ontology.

I know of Etienne Gilson's *Being and some philosophers* ( L'être et l'essence in French) and of Ahumada's *History of Western Ontology* .

Are there other books that aim at presenting the history of metaphysics, and specially of ontology; I'm looking for a book that concentrates specially on the doctrine of categories and that would aim at explaining the way the ontological question has evolved through time.

Comment: Look at [Grondin, Introduction to Metaphysics: From Parmenides to Levinas](https://books.google.com/books?id=6Kvn-xYnWX8C&source=gbs_navlinks_s),  [Moore, The Evolution of Modern Metaphysics](https://books.google.com/books?id=vo-ZLmfwe_oC&source=gbs_navlinks_s),  [Chernyakov, The Ontology of Time](https://books.google.com/books?id=ChH0hjaq91EC&source=gbs_navlinks_s), and [Slowik, The Deep Metaphysics of Space: An Alternative History and Ontology](https://books.google.com/books?id=HBZADQAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Comment: @Conifold. Thanks for these interesting references!

Comment: This answer by @Mr.Kennedy I found enlightening re. the history of the term "metaphysics". Particularly the point underscored in my comment below.